# About replicating/generating a lot of div css

Tags: css, html, browser, scale

For an project I need to **as efficiently as possible** make a world map out of little square divs of approximately 20x20px.

However because I need the div sizes to scale with the browser I am currently using div's with a width of 1% and height of 2%, which on a 16:10 screen looks roughly square.

I have a div called "world" filled with lots of little divs like:

```
<div id="world1" onclick="">&nbsp;</div>
```

each of these divs is paired with css as follows:

```
#world1 {
    background: url(/images/1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 1%;
    height: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 79%;
    left: 91%;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#world1:hover {
    background-position: 0 -20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I figured that the easiest way to make the map is to generate the code for the divs and corresponding css so that divs with names "world1" through to "world20000" are placed at positions ranging from

```
top:1%;
left: 1%;
```

to

```
top:100%;
left: 100%;
```

and then I would go through by hand and delete divs covering the oceans on my map to create a world map.

**How can I generate all this code, or better still is there an easier way to do this, because my solution certainly is not elegant or efficient.**

Also does anyone have a more elegant solution for keeping the div's square in all browser sizes and just scaling the squares with the browser window?

Comment: If you want to have squares of 20px x 20px why do you use dimensions of 1% and 2% instead of 20px and 20px?

Comment: because I need the divs to be approximately 20x20 in a 1920x1680 browser but scale with the browser window. This is what i need to do: http://www.webdesign.org/img_articles/3244/5.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few lines in Perl will do the dirty job for you.

> I figured that the easiest way to make the map is to generate the code
>   for the divs and corresponding css so that divs with names "world1"
>   through to "world20000" are placed at positions ranging from...

It would be easier if you do not place it in `absolute` positions, but used `float:left`, added as many squares you want to fill an entire row, and later use `clear:left` to jump to another row. Not more than 20 line in Perl.

Comment: OK I will do float:left but I dont know perl, can you help me with the code?

Comment: Of course I can help you: I can answer all your questions :) but I won't write it for you. Also, If you you want to handle somehow all those 8.000 tiles, you WILL need to learn and use some scripting language

Comment: Thanks, but i dont even know where to begin with perl. Can you please link me some tutorials on how to do this type of thing? Thanks

Comment: `#! /usr/bin/perl
@no = (1 .. 20000);
foreach(@no) {
 print "<div id=\"world@no\" onclick=\"javascript:showDiv_postscreen(); javascript:hideDiv_welcomebuttons()\">&nbsp;</div>\n"; 
}`. This is my perl script but how do I get it to re-write the sentence with a new variable each time?

Comment: Use either `$_` or explicitly express variable name afret `foreach`.